# foreign key constraint, blog post, acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs, sql-delete, acts-as-votable

So I installed the gem acts_as_votable or whatever it's called. Great little voting system. However in my admin when I go to delete the blog post, I get a foreign key constraint failed error message with the sqlite. I know it has to do with db tables where if you try to delete a record on one table that has a foreign key on another table, that causes an issue unless on_delete: :cascade is defined for the foreign key, etc. I'm not sure how I can do this for the acts_as_votable gem. Anyone know? Thanks!

blog model:

```
class HomeBlog < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  has_many :hashtaggings
  has_many :hashtags, through: :hashtaggings

  acts_as_votable

  def all_hashes=(names)
    self.hashtags = names.split(",").map do |name|
      Hashtag.where(name: name.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end

  def all_hashes
    self.hashtags.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end
end
```

blog controller:

```
class Admin::HomeBlogsController < Admin::AdminController

  before_action :set_home_blog, only: [:show, :destroy]


  def destroy
    @admin_home_blog.destroy!
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admin_home_blogs_path, notice: 'Blog post was successfully deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_home_blog
      @admin_home_blog = Admin::HomeBlog.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def admin_home_blog_params
      params.require(:home_blog).permit(:name, :entry, :image, :all_hashes)
    end
  end
```

The page view:

```
<h3 id="blog-index-title">Blog Posts</h3>


<span class="pagination"><%= will_paginate @admin_home_blogs %></span>
<% @admin_home_blogs.each do |h| %>

<div id="admin-blog-index">
  <%= link_to h.name, h %> | <button type="button"><%= link_to "delete", admin_home_blog_path(h), :style=>'color:white', method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}%></button>
</div><br />
<% end %>
```

Error message:

SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "home_blogs" WHERE "home_blogs"."id" = ?

Comment: Can you share you post model, or blog model whatever you are trying to delete, or if the error is highlighting something else please add that to the question so we can try to help out.

Comment: @Rockwell Rice, I updated the question with my code from various places. Hope that sheds a little more light. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is you need to destroy the records that rely on the post when deleting the post.

```
... 

has_many :hashtaggings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :hashtags, through: :hashtaggings, dependent: :destroy

...
```

Comment: I thought it was this too, before I tried generating a migration that did something similar to your answer in the model. However that didn't work. I just now deleted the migration, tried your dependent: :destroy out in the model and still no luck...same error.

Comment: So there is a relationship that is stopping this.  What other relationships involve a blog post?

Comment: thanks @Rockwell Rice. I resolved it. Dropped some old tables I didn't end up needing and removed a column called home_blog_id from a table that I didn't need it on and that did the trick. Phew! Crisis averted, until the next one...